# Custom search through ArrayList for array names

Tags: android, search, arraylist, filter, adapter

I'm trying to implement search filter with `getFilter` method in my custom adapter.

There are two models of search through the list.

- search for `title` of an item,
- search for `genre[]` of an item.

(*But I'm just talking about `genre` here*).

The below code is working fine, but what I need is just a little more customized way to search in `genre[]`.

What I'm trying to achieve is: (***What I want***):

`multi-keyword` searching, each category separated with`,`. example: `genre1,genre2`

***(What I have done)***:

When I type `genre1,genre2` then it gives the items that have this sequence in genres, it won't give  `genre1,genre3,genre2` , or just `genre1`.

Can you help, please?

***getFilter:***

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            dataList = (List<ProductLocal>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            List<ProductLocal> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataListFilter.size(); i++) {
                ProductLocal dataNames = dataListFilter.get(i);

                String genreStr = "";
                for (String str : dataNames.getGenre()) {
                    genreStr += str + ",";
                }

                if (dataNames.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString()) 
                 || genreStr.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString())) {
                    filteredList.add(dataNames);
                }
            }
            results.count = filteredList.size();
            results.values = filteredList;
            return results;
        }

    };
    return filter;
}
```

Comment: @DastakWall Do u want a kotlin answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIU you want a song to match the fiter if any of these 2 conditions are met:

1. Song's title starts with whole search text
2. The song has a genre that contains a part of the search text separated by `,` (comma)

If this is so, try following search logic:

```
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
        {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            List<ProductLocal> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
            String searchText = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            String[] split = searchText.split(",");
            ArrayList<String> searchGenres = new ArrayList<String>(split.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
            {
                // remove spaces
                String trim = split[i].trim();
                // skip empty entries
                if (trim.length() > 0)
                    searchGenres.add(trim);
            }

            for (ProductLocal dataNames : dataListFilter)
            {
                // filter by title
                if (dataNames.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith(searchText))
                {
                    filteredList.add(dataNames);
                }
                else
                {
                    // filter by genres
                    // search for at least one common genre between song and search text
                    outer:
                    for (String songGenre : dataNames.getGenre())
                    {
                        for (String searchGenre : searchGenres)
                        {
                            if (songGenre.toLowerCase().contains(searchGenre))
                            {
                                filteredList.add(dataNames);
                                break outer;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            results.count = filteredList.size();
            results.values = filteredList;
            return results;
        }
```

The only tricky place here is `break outer;`. This is a Java syntax to break out from two `for` loops at the same time. The idea here is that if we've found a match by some genre between `constraint` and a song, we add the song to the `filteredList` and don't want to add it again if there are more matching genres.

P.S. if filtering by many search genres becomes a performance issue, you may consider building single RegEx to match all search terms at once or  implementing [Aho–Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

Please try by splitting constraint string like below:

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            dataList = (List<ProductLocal>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            List<ProductLocal> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < dataListFilter.size(); i++) {
                ProductLocal dataNames = dataListFilter.get(i);

                int count = 0;
                String[] terms = constraint.toString().split(",");

                for (int j = 0; j < terms.length; j++) {

                    String term = terms[j];
                    for (String str : dataNames.getGenre()) {

                        if (str.equals(term) || str.contains(term)) {
                            count++;
                            if (count == terms.length) {
                                filteredList.add(dataNames);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            results.count = filteredList.size();
            results.values = filteredList;
            return results;
        }

    };
    return filter;
}
```

Comment: It's not working, it's fine for the first keyword, but after inserting `,`  list returns empty

Comment: please try edited answer and let me know if it works.

Comment: The same, but this time after split, list will remain with found items on the first keyword, with no function for any other input

Comment: can you please add more code so i can try it with myself.

Comment: I've deleted all my project's unnecessary files and uploaded it here(Android Studio)  : http://symphonyrecords.ir/apps/Project.zip

Comment: You can find getFilter method in this adapter: `design/LocalAdapter`

Comment: check updated answer. I've tested it and it works,and please make sure you have put "," as a separator character.

Comment: Are you sure? because still, filter has no function on list after `,`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145933/discussion-between-manish-karena-and-s-r).

Answer (score 0):

You can split search term by `,`

```
   String[] searmTearmArray= serachTerm.split(",");
```

now using `for` loop you can search these terms.

Comment: There is no error, but when I type genres in sequences like `violin,light` then it gives the result that has this sequence in genres, it won't give the items that have  `violin,electric,light`.